# CoUninitialize function. How to check for errors and how to wait for completion

Tags: c, com

An Ansi-C function calls [CoUninitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The Syntax is:

```
void CoUninitialize(void);
```

I can not see any options for error Handling, how can i check if CoUninitialize was successful?

During unit testing there is an odd behaviour where i see COM calls fail on every second use of my implementation. I think it may result from some unhandled temporal coupling. The documentation does not tell me if CoUninitialize is blocking or not. If it isn't, how do i wait for it to finish?

Comment: Do you call `CoInitialize`/`CoInitializeEx` anywhere in unit testing? If so, what kind of COM apartment do you initialize (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150777)?

Comment: It is very nice when api functions make an execution guarantee.  Even nicer in a unit test is that you can dismiss any function that gets put to the test billions of times every day for the past 20 years.  Test failed, write the bug report.  And don't make the same mistake you made here, "odd behavior" is not an appropriate bug description, most any dev will quickly dismiss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CoUninitialize` is blocking. It does not report success/failure status because failure to uninitialize is irrecoverable: attempt to uninitialize with outstanding COM activity (esp. marshaling) is likely to eventually cause access violation. COM cleanup does the best it could, but it cannot terminate just everything. Then remains that stay alive after blocking `CoUninitialize` call completes, start being dangerous.

On your side, you are basically expected to blindly pair your COM initialization calls, those which succeeded, with `CoUninitialize` once you made sure you terminated all your COM activity prior to the call.

> ... COM calls fail on every second use

Perhaps you should focus on these failures. Their relation to `CoUninitialize` could be that you call `CoUninitialize` too early, otherwise there should be a different cause. Or, you simply not pairing initialize/uninitialize calls correctly.